# How can I make a summary using grouping method from jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, grouping

I have a problem with summaries using jqgrid. I have a column, where i have minutes and hours and i want to sum them.

```
{name:'worked',index:'worked', width:'5%',title: false, align:"right",sortable:true,summaryType:'sum', summaryTpl:'<b>Total: {0}</b>'},
 groupingView : {
            groupField : ['worked'], 
            groupSummary : [true], 
            groupColumnShow : [true],
            groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'], 
            groupCollapse : false, 
            groupOrder: ['asc']
        },
```

this is my code, it works, if i have integer number. but i want to add minutes+hours.
I also upload an image  where the output is NaN [image]. how can i manage that? thank you in advance.

[image]

```
var fields = new Array("txName","ddManager","ddStatus","ddEtapa","ddGrupare");

var url = $.url(window.location.href.replace("#",""));
var sortname = url.param("sortname");
var sortorder = url.param("sortorder");
var pag =  url.param("page"); // dupa salvare proiecte
var page = url.param("page");

window.onhashchange = function() {
        jQuery("#list2").trigger("reloadGrid");

}
function toMinutes(hhmmString) {
    var parts = hhmmString.split(':');
    return (+parts[0]) * 60 + (+parts[1]); 
}

function toHHMMString(minutes) {
    var hh   = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var mm = minutes - (hh * 60);

    if (hh < 10) {
        hh   = "0" + hh;
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = "0" + mm;
    }

    return hh + ':' + mm;
}

function timeSummary(val, name, record) {
    return toHHMMString(toMinutes(val || '00:00') + toMinutes(record[name] || '00:00'));
}
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({

    url:'/proiecte/json/',
    datatype: "json",

    colNames:['Nume proiect <span>(click dreapta pe un proiect pentru actiuni)</span>','',
    'Client', 'Manager','Etapa', 'Deadline','Lucru recent','Estimat','Lucrat','',''],

    colModel:[

        {name:'name',index:'name', sortable:true, width:'15%',title: false},

        {name:'finished',index:'finished', width:'2%',title: false},

        {name:'client',index:'client', width:'7%',sortable:true,title: false},

        {name:'managerid',index:'managerid',sortable:true, width:'7%',title: false,editable: true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{value:getUsers}},

        {name:'etapa',index:'etapa', width:'7%',title: false,editable: true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{value:getEtapaName}},

        {name:'deadline',index:'deadline', width:'7%',title: false,editable: true, align:"right"},

        {name:'lastactivity',index:'lastactivity', width:'6%',title: false,editable: true, align:"right"},     

        {name:'estimated',index:'estimated', width:'3%',title: false,editable: true, formatter:'integer', align:"right"},     

        {name:'worked',index:'worked', width:'8%',title: false, align:"right",sortable:true,
        summaryType:timeSummary, summaryTpl:'<b>Total: {0}</b>'},

        {name:'remove',index:'remove', width:'2%', sortable:false},

        {name:'date',index:'date', width:'4%',sortable:true, hidden: true,  summaryType:'sum', summaryTpl:'<b>Total: {0}</b>'}




    ],
    rowNum:20,    

    sortname: sortname,
    sortorder: sortorder,
    page: pag,

    viewrecords: true,

    caption:"",

    autowidth: true,

    shrinkToFit: true,

    width: '100%',

    height: '100%',

    altRows: true,

    altClass: '',

    gridview: true, //groupingGroupBy
    groupingView : {
        groupField : ['worked'], 
        groupSummary : [true], 
        groupColumnShow : [true],
       // groupText: ['<b>{0} - {1} reg(s)</b>']
        groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'], 
        groupCollapse : false, 
        groupOrder: ['asc']
    },
    footerrow: true,

    loadComplete:function(request){
        var workedTotal = jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getCol', 'date', false, 'sum');
        workedTotal = Math.floor(workedTotal / 3600)+" ore ";
        $('#totalRows').html(request.total + " rezultate");

        $(this).jqGrid('footerData','set',
        {name:'TOTAL', worked:workedTotal});

        $("[aria-describedby='list2_name']", this).contextMenu('myMenu1',{ 

            /*onContextMenu: function(e) {

                var rowId = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");



                if($(e.target).closest("a").attr("class"))

                {   

                    $("#add").html('<a href="taskuri/edit/?add=1&pid='+rowId+'&uid=<?=$userid?>#?txName=&ddProject=-1&ddUser=<?=$userid?>&ddStatus=0&ddAssigner=-1&deadline=&page=1&sortname=taskid&sortorder=desc">Adauga task</a>');

                    $("#edit").html('<a href="taskuri#?txName=&ddProject='+rowId+'&ddUser=-1&ddStatus=-1&ddAssigner=-1&deadline=&page=1&sortname=taskid&sortorder=desc">Taskurile proiectului</a>');

                    $("#time").html('<a href="timp#?period=&ddProject='+rowId+'&ddUser=-1&ddActivity=-1&txTask=&page=1&sortname=date&sortorder=asc">Inregistrari timp proiect</a>');

                    $("#copyy").html('<a id="copy" href="proiecte/popUpProiecte/?&pid='+rowId+'">Copiaza task-uri</a>');

                    $("a#copy").fancybox({


                        'width'             : 400,

                        'height'            : 200,

                        'autoScale'         : false,

                        'transitionIn'      : 'none',

                        'transitionOut'     : 'none',

                        'scrolling'         : 'no',

                        'type'              : 'iframe'
                     })
                    return true;    
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }*/
        });
        $("#paging").html(request.userdata.pager);

        $(".numb").click(function() { 

            $("#list2").trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:parseInt($(this).text())}]);

        });
        doPagination();
        showConfirm();
        formatUrl();
        setBackUrl();

        $("#empty").hide(); 

        if(request.total == 0)

            $("#empty").show();
        /*$("#list2 tr").find("td:eq(8)").each(function(index, item) {
            var prog = 0;
            try {
                prog = parseInt($(item).text());
            }
            catch(ex) {
                prog = -1;
            }
            if(prog >=0)
                $(item).html('<div class="grafic"></div>').find("div.grafic").progressbar({ value: prog });
        });*/
    } ,
    beforeRequest:function() {
        parseUrl();

        var manager = jQuery("#ddManager").val();

        var status = jQuery("#ddStatus").val();

        var name = jQuery("#txName").val();

        var etapa = jQuery("#ddEtapa").val(); 

        var grupare = jQuery("#ddGrupare").val(); 

        jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"/proiecte/json/?manager="+manager+"&status="+status+"&name="+name+"&etapa="+etapa+"&grupare="+grupare});



    },

    cellEdit: true,

    cellsubmit: 'remote',

    cellurl: "/proiecte/editCell",

    afterSaveCell : function(rowid,iCol,cellcontent,value){
            $.post('/proiecte/editCell',{'colName':iCol,'pid': rowid, 'cellValue':cellcontent  }, function(data) {
                $("#list2").trigger("reloadGrid");  

            });

    },
    afterEditCell: function (id,name,val,iRow,iCol){

        if(name=='deadline') {

            jQuery("#"+iRow+"_deadline","#list2").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});

        }else if (name=='lastactivity'){
            jQuery("#"+iRow+"_lastactivity","#list2").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});
        }

    }
});
jQuery("#btnFilter").click(search);
function search(x) {
     x = formatUrl();
     jQuery("#list2").trigger("reloadGrid");

     $('#filter .formItem:first input').focus();
}
//filtrare
$("#txName").keyup(function(){
    search();
});
$("#ddManager").change(function(){
    search();
});
$("#ddStatus").change(function(){
    search();
});
$("#ddEtapa").change(function(){
    search();
});

function formatUrl(p) {

    var hash = "?";
    $.each(fields, function(index, value) { 
          hash += value + "=" + $("#"+value).val() + "&";
    });
    //$("#list2").jqGrid('setGridParam',{page:page});
    pageCheck = $("#list2").jqGrid('getGridParam','page');
    hash+="page="+pageCheck;
    hash+="&sortname="+$("#list2").jqGrid('getGridParam','sortname');
    hash+="&sortorder="+$("#list2").jqGrid('getGridParam','sortorder');

    window.location.hash = hash;    

    $('#filter .formItem:first input').focus(); 
    return hash;  

}


function remove(){
    if(confirm("Doriti sa stergeti proiectul selectat?")==true) {
        $.post('/proiecte/delete', {'pid': projectid }, function(data) {
            $("#list2").trigger("reloadGrid");  
        });
    }
}

function setBackUrl() {

    $("#list2 tr td[role=gridcell] a").each(function(index,item) {          

        $(item).attr("href",$(item).attr("href")+window.location.hash);         

    });

}


function parseUrl() {   

    var url = $.url(window.location.href.replace("#",""));



    $.each(fields, function(index, value) { 

        if(url.param(value)!=null)

            $("#"+value).val(url.param(value));

        //alert(url.param(value));

    });

}

function getUsers(){

    var projectid = jQuery('#list2').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    var items;
    items = JSON.parse(
        $.ajax({
          url: '/proiecte/getUsers/?projectid='+projectid,
          async: false
        }).responseText);    
    return items;
}
function getEtapaName(){

   // var projectid = jQuery('#list2').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    var items;
    items = JSON.parse(
        $.ajax({
          url: '/proiecte/getEtapaName',
          async: false
        }).responseText);    
    return items;
}
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false}); 


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#filter .formItem:first input').focus();
});
```

/**************************************************Gruparea*****************************************************/
    $("#ddGrupare").change(function () {
        var groupingName = $(this).val();

```
    if (groupingName != -1) {
        $("#list2").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', groupingName, {
             groupOrder : ['desc']
        });
    }else{
        $("#list2").jqGrid('groupingRemove');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need some JavaScript functions to do the calculation, for example like this:

```
function toMinutes(hhmmString) {
    var parts = hhmmString.split(':');
    return (+parts[0]) * 60 + (+parts[1]); 
}

function toHHMMString(minutes) {
    var hh   = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var mm = minutes - (hh * 60);

    if (hh < 10) {
        hh   = "0" + hh;
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = "0" + mm;
    }

    return hh + ':' + mm;
}

function timeSummary(val, name, record) {
    return toHHMMString(toMinutes(val || '00:00') + toMinutes(record[name] || '00:00'));
}
```

Then you need to use the fact that `summaryType` can take function as a value:

```
{name: 'worked', index: 'worked', width: '5%', title: false, align: 'right', sortable: true, summaryType: timeSummary, summaryTpl: '<b>Total: {0}</b>' }
```

This should give the desired result.

Comment: thx for your answer, you have a syntax error "+m;;" but this is not the problem. The problem is I don't get it . You created a function with 3 params. and when you call it here "summaryType: workedSummary", isn't it should look like "summaryType: workedSummary(integer,string,string)". At the moment it doesn't work neither way. It just show me the "Loading" process. So any idea ? thx

Comment: @Chester The function signature and the way it is configured is correct, you can check that here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping (go to coldModel Options --> summaryType).The behaviour suggest some exception in JavaScript so maybe there is somethign in datat I haven't forsean, can you post a link to the grid with some smaple data? Maybe a jsFiddle demo? If not please check if there are no information about the JavaScript exceptions in your browser.

Comment: @Chester I have rewritten solution to use minutes and generalized a bit, can you check now?

Comment: @tpeczekI updated my post with an image,  with the result of your method. Question : why when i do an alert of val or name or record in timeSummary() it is empty ?

Comment: @Chester If properly configured, the jqGrid will call `timeSummary` for every row (this is why you pass it to the option only by name, jqGrid requires the actual function not its result) - for first row the val should be empty and for next rows it should be the result of previous call. The `NaN` error would suggest that your values fail the conversion. Can you provide any raw data that would allow debugging?

Comment: @thx for helping me, you can extract data from the image that i have uploaded recently

Comment: @Chester Nope, I can only see the representation. This doesn't make me sure what the actual data are which leads to making assumptions. Here you can find an assumption based jsFiddle which works: http://jsfiddle.net/tpeczek/muh7V/ - there must be something odd with your data so I need to look at it

Comment: can you see the column before the time column? with the values(100 and 102) Can you post a function which can sum the cells value ? using grouping of course. I want to understand how does all this system work. Thx a lot !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43522/discussion-between-tpeczek-and-chester)