# JQGrid custom summary match

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, summary

Have successfully used JQGrid for a few projects, but struggling to get it to do what I want in this example.

I think I need to create a custom summaryType that checks whether records match, rather than sum, avg, min, max etc.

[image]

I need to check whether record 'Us', matches 'Them' and display the text 'Match' where the red X's are, could anyone give me some pointers on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly simple when you understand how it works, thanks to the comments on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633718/how-can-i-make-a-summary-using-grouping-method-from-jqgrid)

> the jqGrid will call your function for every row (this is why you pass it to the option only by name, jqGrid requires the actual function not its result) - for first row the val should be empty and for next rows it should be the result of previous call.

Set a summaryType in your colModel as your function name, and use these functions

```
function numberMatch(val, name, record) {
    if (val || 0 - record[name] == 0) {
        return "Match";
    } else {
        return "unmatched";
    }    
}

function textMatch(val, name, record) {
    if (val || '' === record[name]) {
        return "Match";
    } else {
        return "unmatched";
    }    
}
```